# Python executes another file

Tags: python, function, call

I made file'DWDfunctional.py' containing the following codes:

```
def ForecastDownloader(system,ModelName,year,Month):
     import cdsapi
     c = cdsapi.Client()
     c.retrieve(
        'seasonal-monthly-single-levels',
        {
            'originating_centre': ModelName,
            'system': system,
            'variable': 'total_precipitation',
            'product_type': 'monthly_mean',
            'year': year,
            'month': Month,
            'area'          : [40, 44, 24, 64],
            'leadtime_month': [
                '1', '2', '3',
                '4', '5', '6',
            ],
            'format': 'netcdf',
        },
        'dwd.nc')
```

Then I called the function in another file:

```
from DWDfunctional.py import ForecastDownloader

ForecastDownloader('2','dwd',2020,2)
```

I am wondering, when I run the above two line codes, python executes another old code in a nother folder!!! and downloads wrong files with wrong file names with no Error!!

Comment: I am wondering again, when I call the function inside 'DWDfunctional.py'  it correctly executes!! and It is correctly runs. But I need call function outside that file.

Comment: after the import, you may check `module.__file__` to see where your module came from. and drop `.py` from the import, just the name should be sufficient.

Comment: How can I check module.__file__

Comment: `ForecastDownloader.__file__`

Comment: Please add this help as answer of this question so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the import, you may check `module.__file__` to see where your `module` came from.

In your particular case, you may check `ForecastDownloader.__file__` that should give you the correct file path.